# How can I get the current page name in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, page-title

What PHP code can be used to retrieve the current page name in a WordPress theme?

All the solutions I have seen so far:

- `the_title()`
- `get_page()->post_name`
- `get_post()`
- etc.

But these don't work for a page that contains post entries. They will all return the name of the latest blog entry.

Stated another way, assume that you have a page created in WordPress with the name "My News". This page is set as the "post page". Add a couple of posts to the page.
Now, what API can be used to retrieve the string "my-news" instead of the name of the latest post?

---

I've found the following variable which seems to work.

```
$wp_query->queried_object->post_name
```

This is actually the URL friendly version of the page name (slug), which is what I was looking for too. This was tested with the default template ([Twenty Ten](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyten/)). I'm really not sure why the two variables given below do not work on my site. Thanks to [*keatch* for the `print_r()` tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837006/how-can-i-get-the-current-page-name-in-wordpress/4837579#4837579).

Now, why is this information hidden so deep down?

Comment: for the Name use:
single_post_title( '', false );
for the slug use:
get_query_var('pagename');

Comment: Here's a detailed post about all the different methods that can be used: https://www.benmarshall.me/get-current-page-name-wordpress/

Answer (score 206, accepted):

The WordPress global variable `$pagename` should be available for you. I have just tried with the same setup you specified.

`$pagename` is defined in the file wp-includes/theme.php, inside the function `get_page_template()`, which is of course is called before your page theme files are parsed, so it is available at any point inside your templates for pages.

- Although it doesn't appear to be documented, the `$pagename` var is only set if you use permalinks. I guess this is because if you don't use them, WordPress doesn't need the page slug, so it doesn't set it up.
- `$pagename` is not set if you use the page as a static front page.

- This is the code inside /wp-includes/theme.php, which uses the solution you pointed out when `$pagename` can't be set:

--

```
if ( !$pagename && $id > 0 ) {
  // If a static page is set as the front page, $pagename will not be set. Retrieve it from the queried object
  $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
  $pagename = $post->post_name;
}
```

Comment: $pagename is empty when used inside header.php. I've tried using the default template (twentyten) and using it immediately after the <body> tag but it is not set. Incidentally, none of the query_vars variables seem to be set at that stage.

Comment: I can't see any reason for the absence of that variable, perhaps I have misunderstood your setup? I understood you are trying to do this inside a page template. Even if you write "echo $pagename" in the first line of header.php it should give you the value. What version of WP are you dealing with?

Comment: You could try a slightly different approach using get_query_var('pagename').

Comment: @AJweb: Yes, it's for a template that I'm building but I'm using the default template for testing, inside header.php. I get the impression that you haven't tested your solution. Do you see the page name when you put an <h1><?php echo $pagename ?></h1> right after the <body> tag in header.php ?

Comment: @Alkaline: Your are right in one thing: My solutions don't work with all setups of WP. But you are wrong in thinking that I hadn't checked my solutions, I did. I post my findings in an edit of my answer so I can format it properly.

Comment: @AJweb: Thanks for the extra research. It adds crucial information. I am using static pages and that explains why $pagename isn't available.

Comment: This did the trick for me: `$pagename = $wp_query->queried_object->post_name;`, just **don't forget** to set `global $wp_query;` before!

Comment: Is there any tool/browser pugin to get the actual page name?

Comment: Code example above is helpful, but it's actually located in `wp-includes/template.php`, not `theme.php`.

Answer (score 46):

My approach to get the slug name of the page:

```
$slug = basename(get_permalink());
```

Comment: This works only if they use pretty url, doesn't it?

Answer (score 28):

```
<?php wp_title(''); ?>
```

This worked for me.

If I understand correctly, you want to get the page name on a page that has post entries.

Answer (score 26):

Ok, you must grab the page title *before* the loop.

```
$page_title = $wp_query->post->post_title;
```

Check for the reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Properties.

Do a

```
print_r($wp_query)
```

before the loop to see all the values of the `$wp_query` object.

Comment: This doesn't work either. If I print the $wp_query object right after the <body> tag I see that the first post object is the blog entry, not the page itself.

However, thanks for the print_r() tip. I could find out the variable that has the info I'm looking for (putting this info in the question).

Comment: echoing out that $page_title var worked for me in the header, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can get the current page, post, or custom post type with the global variable `$post`:

```
echo $post->post_title
```

Note: In a function or class you'll need to specify `global $post;` prior to trying to use `$post`.

If you have loops on your page, make sure you end each loop with `wp_reset_postdata();` to set `$post` back to the default item being displayed (the page).

Note, the 'post_title' variable is also available for any custom loop / query... including menu items and media attachments... everything in WordPress is a 'post'.

Comment: This answer is from 2012, is there any knowledge as to if this method will still work with more recent WP?

Comment: Yep it will—WP's core handling of post types has not changed

Answer (score 12):

We just need to use the "post" global variable:

```
global $post;
echo $post->post_title;
```

This will echo the current page/post title.

Comment: What about HTML [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)?

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking to access the current page from within your functions.php file (so, *before* the loop, before `$post` is populated, before `$wp_query` is initialized, etc...) you really have no choice but to access the server variables themselves and extract the requested page from the query string.

```
$page_slug = trim( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] , '/' )
```

Note that this is a "dumb" solution. It doesn't know, for instance that the page with the slug 'coming-soon' is also `p=6`. And it assumes that your permalink settings are set to `pagename` (which they should be anyway!).

Still, can be a useful little trick if you have a controlled scenario. I'm using this in a situation where I wish to redirect non-logged in visitors to a "coming soon" page; but I have to make sure that I'm not throwing them into the dreaded "redirect loop", so I need to exclude the "coming soon" page from this rule:

```
global $pagenow;
if (
        ! is_admin() &&
        'wp-login.php' != $pagenow &&
        'coming-soon' != trim( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] , '/' ) &&
        ! is_user_logged_in()
){
   wp_safe_redirect( 'coming-soon' );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe that the [Roots starter theme](https://github.com/roots/roots/blob/6.5.0/lib/titles.php) has a fantastic function to get the current page title. It is very hackable, covers all bases, and can be easily used with the `wp_title` hook.

```
/**
 * Page titles
 */
function roots_title() {
  if (is_home()) {
    if (get_option('page_for_posts', true)) {
      echo get_the_title(get_option('page_for_posts', true));
    } else {
      _e('Latest Posts', 'roots');
    }
  } elseif (is_archive()) {
    $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy'));
    if ($term) {
      echo $term->name;
    } elseif (is_post_type_archive()) {
      echo get_queried_object()->labels->name;
    } elseif (is_day()) {
      printf(__('Daily Archives: %s', 'roots'), get_the_date());
    } elseif (is_month()) {
      printf(__('Monthly Archives: %s', 'roots'), get_the_date('F Y'));
    } elseif (is_year()) {
      printf(__('Yearly Archives: %s', 'roots'), get_the_date('Y'));
    } elseif (is_author()) {
      $author = get_queried_object();
      printf(__('Author Archives: %s', 'roots'), $author->display_name);
    } else {
      single_cat_title();
    }
  } elseif (is_search()) {
    printf(__('Search Results for %s', 'roots'), get_search_query());
  } elseif (is_404()) {
    _e('Not Found', 'roots');
  } else {
    the_title();
  }
}
```

Comment: May I ask, what is so fantastic about this function? It's basically defining titles by hand. Do SEO plugins play along with that?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$pagename = get_query_var('pagename');
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order (respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12349997/edit), not here in comments).

Answer (score 5):

I have come up with a simpler solution.

Get the returned value of the page name from wp_title(). If empty, print homepage name, otherwise echo the wp_title() value.

```
<?php $title = wp_title('', false); ?>
```

Remember to remove the separation with the first argument and then set display to false to use as an input to the variable. Then just bung the code between your heading, etc. tags.

```
<?php if ( $title == "" ) : echo "Home"; else : echo $title; endif; ?>
```

It worked a treat for me and ensuring that the first is declared in the section where you wish to extract the `$title`, this can be tuned to return different variables.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
$title = get_the_title($post);
$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);

echo $title;
echo $parent_title;
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the easiest to use:

```
<?php single_post_title(); ?>
```

Comment: This call returns the last post name, not the page name that contains the posts, at least that's what I understand from the online doc without testing it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I made a new header for my page and this pulled the name of the page as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Show the title before the loop starts:

```
$page_title = $wp_query->post->post_title;
```

Answer (score 2):

One option, if you're looking for the actual queried page, rather than the page ID or slug is to intercept the query:

```
add_action('parse_request', 'show_query', 10, 1);
```

Within your function, you have access to the $wp object and you can get either the pagename or the post name with:

```
function show_query($wp){
     if ( ! is_admin() ){ // heck we don't need the admin pages
         echo $wp->query_vars['pagename'];
         echo $wp->query_vars['name'];
     }
}
```

If, on the other hand, you really need the post data, the first place to get it (and arguably in this context, the best) is:

```
add_action('wp', 'show_page_name', 10, 1);

function show_page_name($wp){
     if ( ! is_admin() ){
        global $post;
        echo $post->ID, " : ", $post->post_name;
     }
}
```

Finally, I realize this probably wasn't the OP's question, but if you're looking for the *Admin* page name, use the global `$pagenow`.

Answer (score 2):

Within the [WordPress *Loop*](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop):

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
/******************************************/
echo get_the_title();
/******************************************/
endwhile; endif;
```

This will show you the current page title.

For reference: *[get_the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)*

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version:

```
$title = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', get_query_var('pagename')));
```

get_query_var('pagename') was just giving me the page slug. So the above replaces all the dashes, and makes the first letter of each word uppercase - so it can actually be used as a title.

Comment: Yes this is working as charm. I was not able to get the page name for blog page. Now i can. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've now found this function on *WordPress Codec*,

*[get queried](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)*

which is a wrapper for `$wp_query->get_queried_object`.

This post put me in the right direction, but it seems that it needs this update.

Answer (score 0):

This also works if you are in the functions.php. It is not the best approach since you have to use the global array, but it works.

1. First, we need to add a filter. There must exist a better filter to use than the template_include, but I don't know all of them. Please point me to the right one.

   ```
   add_filter( 'template_include', 'var_template_include', 1000 );
   function var_template_include( $template ){
       global $wp_query;
       $GLOBALS['current_page'] = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->post_name;
       return $template;
   }
   ```
2. Avoid using the variable directly

   ```
   function get_current_page( $echo =  false ) {
       if( !isset( $GLOBALS['current_page'] ) )
           return false;
       return $GLOBALS['current_page'];
   }
   ```
3. Now you can use the function `get_current_page()` in any other part of the functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using, as of 2018:

```
<section id="top-<?=(is_front_page() ? 'home' : basename(get_permalink()));?>">
```