# Wordpress is_page function to display alternative logo

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

I have a wordpress theme where the logo is defined in header.php but I would like to display a different logo if they go to a certain page.

The code I am using is below, but it just returns a blank white page when visit the site when using it.

Any ideas?

```
<?php 
    if(is_page('compliance')){
    <a href="http://www.url.com" class="logo"><img src="http://www.url.com/images/logo2.png" alt="url.com"/></a>
    }
    else { <a href="http://www.url.com" class="logo"><img src="http://www.url.com/images/logo1.png" alt="url.com"/></a>
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you can not close <?php ?> before html tag so reffered comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
    if(is_page('compliance')){
?>
    <a href="http://www.url.com" class="logo"><img src="http://www.url.com/images/logo2.png" alt="url.com"/></a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="http://www.url.com" class="logo"><img src="http://www.url.com/images/logo1.png" alt="url.com"/></a>
<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$pagename = get_query_var('pagename');
if($pagname == 'compliance'){ ...
```

You can read this : [How to get the current page name in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837006/how-to-get-the-current-page-name-in-wordpress)

Comment: the OP wants to use `is_page` therefore your variable is a bit unnecessary