# Only show line of code on a specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a bunch of different menu pages (using custom fields) for a local restaurant and want to show a PDF menu only one one of these pages. I am trying to add a line of code to the template for the Menu pages that only shows up on the page with the slug 'wine-list'.

Here is what I did but it does not work:

```
<?php if(is_single( 'wine-list' )){
    echo '<a href="LINK-TO-PDF.pdf" target="_blank">View our full wine list</a>'; 
}
else{} ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the current page name in Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837006/how-to-get-the-current-page-name-in-wordpress)

Comment: Why even use your conditional statement? Just put the link on "that" page.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That wouldn't work with this page template

Comment: Why not... HTML is HTML, that's what I do with some of the WordPress sites I administer. What's so special about "that" particular template? Is it because it doesn't let you hard code it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- so how would i write that?

Comment: Where you already have echo'ed code with existing links/content and inside PHP, just do `echo '<a href="LINK-TO-PDF.pdf" target="_blank">View our full wine list</a>';` as you have it now. You don't even need the conditional statement. If outside of PHP, just do `<a href="LINK-TO-PDF.pdf" target="_blank">View our full wine list</a>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- if he did that it wouldn't show up on ONLY the wine-list page but every page.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't link the PDF in the post content on the backend of WordPress?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee there is a reason but I am not skilled enough to tell you why. Mark's response below worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the if [is_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

```
<?php if(is_page( 'wine-list' )){
    echo '<a href="LINK-TO-PDF.pdf" target="_blank">View our full wine list</a>'; 
}
else{} ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `is_page()` will work for testing on a Single Blog Post.

Comment: It worked! Thanks Mark with a K! (I'm Marc with a C)