# Wordpress pass page name to template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom template set on all my Pages, it loads the template fine, now I need to switch into fetching data from the database based on the post name.

*mysite.com/cars* -> page name [**cars**]

Page [**cars**] loads the home.php template:

### home.php

```
<?php 

get_header();

//get name of page [cars] use it to retrieve from a custom table 
//with the primary key [cars]

get_footer();
?>
```

do I have to parse the URL to extract the name or is there someway I can provide wordpress the name. I dont see an option to set it on the posts page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want

```
$pagename
```

The WP global variable $pagename should be available for you.

$pagename is defined in the file wp-includes/theme.php, inside the function get_page_template(), which is of course called before your page theme files are parsed, so it is available at any point inside your templates for pages.

- Although it doesn't appear to be documented, the $pagename var is
  only set if you use permalinks. I guess this is because if you don't
  use them, WP doesn't need the page slug, so it doesn't set it up.
- $pagename is not set if you use the page as a static front page.

see [How to get the current page name in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837006/how-to-get-the-current-page-name-in-wordpress)