# How to assign a class "active" to the li element based on current URL and click event using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, addclass, removeclass

I am trying to create a menu where a class "active" is assigned to the page whenever it's selected and loaded. Right now it is applied only to the index page by default.

My menu snippet:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php">Main</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://localhost/wp/news">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://localhost/wp/contacts">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Main, News Contacts? are three different pages in php?

Comment: Are you using WordPress?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where exactly do you want to add class? In <li> i suppose?

Comment: But he has to remove existing class on other li also

Comment: @OP, are links being formed in some sort of loops ?

Comment: Are links being formed from the db? i.e. are you forming them on server side?

Comment: @TariqHusain yes, they are in php, using a Wordpress theme template

Comment: @Tristan yes I am using Wordpress. All of my pages use the same template.

Comment: @ZeeshanHyder Sorry if it was unclear. I want to add "active" class to my li, yes, depending on the selected and loaded page.

Comment: @RayonDabre they aren't as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Azim :see my answer .. with demo

Comment: @Azim : see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. Its working at my end.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".nav.navbar-nav li").click(function(){
        jQuery(".nav.navbar-nav li").removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        })
var loc = window.location.href;
 jQuery(".nav.navbar-nav li").removeClass('active');
    jQuery(".nav.navbar-nav li a").each(function() {
        if (loc.indexOf(jQuery(this).attr("href")) != -1) {

            jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
        }
    });
});     
</script>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php">Main</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://localhost/wp/news">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://localhost/wp/contacts">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this just adds class "active" to all the li elements

Comment: You want to add class to li tag based on current page. right??

Comment: how this can be a answer and working your end ... only those li has to be active which are clicked

Comment: Yes. But when I use the code you provided I get my css from "active" class applied to all of my menu li elements.

Comment: Let me know if you want to add class active based on current page url. I will happy to help you.

Comment: Results in the same behaviour - adds class "active" to the clicked menu li but dissapears after that page is loaded

Comment: Try latest answer update by me. Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.
***Tried and tested*** ,, See the [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mewf59n2/)   and [**UPDATED DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mewf59n2/5/)

```
    $(".navbar-nav").find("a").click(function(){

               $(".navbar-nav").find("li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");




        })

        $( window ).load(function() {


         var which_page=window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                    $(".navbar-nav").find("a").each(function(){
                    if($(this).attr("href") == which_page)
                    {
                     $(this).addClass("active");

                    }

                   })



        });
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mewf59n2/5/)

Comment: tested it and it adds "active" class to the li element I'm clicking on but dissapears right after the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

i assume if you are using php ur page would be like this.
  just define a $active variable in each page.

```
<?php 
//Main.php
 $active = "Main";
?>

<?php 
//news.php
 $active = "News";
?>

<?php 
//Contacts.php
 $active = "Contacts";
?>
```

Then your html would be like this.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="<?php echo $active=='Main'? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php">Main</a></li>
     <li class="<?php echo $active=='News'? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="http://localhost/wp/news">News</a></li>
     <li class="<?php echo $active=='Contacts'? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="http://localhost/wp/contacts">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be better:-

```
$(".navbar-nav").children("a").click(function(){
    $(".navbar-nav").children("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery:-

```
$("div.navbar-nav").on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

If you want to keep last selected value after page load based on anchor tag url then add this lines also.

```
// get the actual pathname:
var path = location.pathname;
// filter menu items to find one that has anchor tag with matching href:
$('.navbar-nav li').filter(function(){
    return '/' + $('a', this).attr('href') === path;
// add class active to the item:
}).addClass('active');
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var pageTitle = window.location.pathname.replace(/^.*\/([^/]*)/, "$1");

        $('.navbar-nav a').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('href').toLowerCase() == pageTitle.toLocaleLowerCase())
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        });
  });
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: tested it and it adds "active" class to the li element I'm clicking on but dissapears right after the page is loaded

Comment: on page load it will be removed. Do you also want to keep your clicked element after page load also?

Comment: I've tested your last edit and it doesn't keep the class "active" on after the selected page loads :(

Comment: Check second option also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in PHP.

**Steps:**

> 1) Create a multi-dimensional array of menus.
>
> 2) Key is the link and value is the text.
>
> 3) Get the current page URL.
>
> 4) Get the last segment of the url using `basename()`.
>
> 5) That will be your current page variable. If its blank, assign it to home page.
>
> 6) Loop over `menus` array.
>
> 7) Display menu `li`s in loop.
>
> 8) If current loop items is equal to current page, add class `active`
>   else, add no class.

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
$menus = array();
$menus['main'] = 'index.php';
$menus['news'] = 'News';
$menus['contacts'] = 'Contacts';
$currentURL = curPageURL();// Get Current url here.
$currentPage = basename($currentURL);
$currentPage = empty($currentPage) ? 'main' : $currentPage;
if (! empty($menus)) {
?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<?php
    foreach ($menus as $lnk => $txt) {
        $activeCls = ($lnk == $currentPage) ? 'active' : '';
?>
     <li class="<?php echo $activeCls;?>"><a href="http://localhost/wp/<?php echo $lnk;?>"><?php echo $txt;?></a></li>
    <?php
    }
?>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this would help you if you can edit your theme.

```
$slug = basename(get_permalink());

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="<?php echo $slug =='Main_page_slug'? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php">Main</a></li>
         <li class="<?php echo $slug =='newpageslug'? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="http://localhost/wp/news">News</a></li>
         <li class="<?php echo $slug =='congtactPageslug'? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="http://localhost/wp/contacts">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
```

there might be some other way to get current page url or title or id, please check here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837006/how-to-get-the-current-page-name-in-wordpress)