# remove statcounter script from one page only

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the statcounter script (which I have in footer) from one page only on a wordpress site so it wouldn't count that page and specifically because of it's hidden element.

I've looked into the plugin php but it doesn't register or enqueue any scripts so I don't know what function to use. Below is a fragment from its php:

```
$sc_position = get_option(key_sc_position);
if ($sc_position=="header") {
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_statcounter');
} else {
    add_action('wp_footer', 'add_statcounter');
}



// The guts of the StatCounter script
function add_statcounter() {
    global $user_level;
    $sc_project = get_option(key_sc_project);
    $sc_security = get_option(key_sc_security);
    $sc_invisible = 0;
    $sc_invisible = get_option('sc_invisible');
    if (
        ( $sc_project > 0 )
     ) {
?>
    <!-- Start of StatCounter Code -->
    <script>
    <!-- 
        var sc_project=<?php echo $sc_project; ?>; 
        var sc_security="<?php echo $sc_security; ?>"; 
<?php 
if($sc_invisible==1) {
    echo "      var sc_invisible=1;\n"; 
}

define('HTTPS', isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && filter_var($_SERVER['HTTPS'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN));
$protocol = defined('HTTPS') ? "https:" : "http:";

?>
        var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
        "https://secure." : "http://www.");
    //-->
document.write("<sc"+"ript src='" +scJsHost +"statcounter.com/counter/counter.js'></"+"script>");
</script>

    <!-- End of StatCounter Code -->
<?php
    }
}
```

I've tried using:

```
function no_stat_counter_scripts() {
    if(!is_page(XXX)){
        global $user_level;
remove_action( 'wp_head', array($user_level, 'add_statcounter') );
remove_action( 'wp_footer', array($user_level, 'add_statcounter') );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'no_stat_counter_scripts' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'no_stat_counter_scripts');
```

but it's not working, anyone has an idea how I can accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

so you see this:

```
$sc_position = get_option(key_sc_position);
if ($sc_position=="header") {
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_statcounter');
} else {
    add_action('wp_footer', 'add_statcounter');
}
```

We don't want to do this if it's a certain page...

In order to get that certain page check this out

[How to get the current page name in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837006/how-to-get-the-current-page-name-in-wordpress)

```
if ($pagename != "thepageyoudontwanttohavestatson")
{
if ($sc_position=="header") {
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_statcounter');
} else {
    add_action('wp_footer', 'add_statcounter');
}
}
```

Meaning, if my current pagename is not equal to the page I want to ignore, then ADD the counters... and get rid of that code you did as far as

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'no_stat_counter_scripts' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'no_stat_counter_scripts');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
<?php
function add_statcounter() {
if(is_page('id or slug of page to exclude')) return;
    global $user_level;
    $sc_project = get_option(key_sc_project);
    $sc_security = get_option(key_sc_security);
    $sc_invisible = 0;
    $sc_invisible = get_option('sc_invisible');
    if ( ( $sc_project > 0 )) {
    ?>
    <!-- Start of StatCounter Code -->
    <script>
    <!-- 
    var sc_project=<?php echo $sc_project; ?>; 
    var sc_security="<?php echo $sc_security; ?>"; 
    <?php 
    if($sc_invisible==1) {
        echo "var sc_invisible=1;\n"; 
    }

    define('HTTPS', isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && filter_var($_SERVER['HTTPS'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN));
    $protocol = defined('HTTPS') ? "https:" : "http:";

    ?>
    var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
    "https://secure." : "http://www.");
    //-->
    document.write("<sc"+"ript src='" +scJsHost +"statcounter.com/counter/counter.js'></"+"script>");
    </script>
    <!-- End of StatCounter Code -->
    <?php
    }
}
```